# Initializing NSMutableArray __strong with an incompatible type of void

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsjsonserialization

This is what is returning the error:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[[appDelegate.Matches objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)indexPath] objectForKey:@"chat"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]] addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:message, @"message", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", appDelegate.userId], @"id", nil]];
```

Comment: You should really cut down on that line-length. Use extra variables if need be - helps readability.

Comment: Not only readability, but also debugging. You can actually see which of the ~10 methods you're calling here is the culprit

Comment: The 21st **International Obfuscated C Code Contest** is coming up... http://www.ioccc.org/ . You really should think of entering.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Holy run-on expression, Batman!"

If you were to separate that out into multiple lines, you could easily see where the problem is.

Or, more likely, the error would mysteriously go away.

The problem is that `addObject:` returns `(void)`, but you are trying to assign the return value of that method to the variable.

Comment: +1 for "Holy run-on expression, Batman!"... oh and the answer ;)

Comment: to simplify the code, it isn't that bad to make run-on expressions is it?

Comment: Your question demonstrates exactly why it is bad;  it hides errors and makes the code more difficult to debug.   How, for example, would you step through in the debugger and see the result of executing just the `[appDelegate.Matches objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)indexPath]` expression?